# Add single quotes to a string

Tags: r, string, concatenation, single-quotes

I try to add single quotes to a string but don't see how to do it. For instance I would like to replace ABC by 'ABC'.

I have played with `paste`, `cat`, `print` but don't see how to do it.

Any solution?

Thanks,
Vincent

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use `paste`:

```
R> paste("'", "ABC", "'", sep="")
[1] "'ABC'"
```

or the new variety

```
R> paste0("'", "ABC", "'")
[1] "'ABC'"
```

Answer (score 24):

Maybe use `sQuote`?

```
sQuote("ABC")
# [1] "'ABC'"
```

This (like its sibling `dQuote`) is frequently used to put quotes around some message or other text that's being printed to the console:

```
cat("ABC", "\n")
# ABC 
cat(sQuote("ABC"), "\n")
# 'ABC'
```

**Do note** (as is documented in `?sQuote`) that, depending on the type of quotes needed for your task, you may need to first reset `options("useFancyQuotes")`. To **ensure** that the function decorates your text with simple upright ASCII quotes, for example, do the following:

```
options(useFancyQuotes = FALSE)
sQuote("ABC")
# [1] "'ABC'"
```

Comment: Wow, my default option was to use fancyQuotes on OS X and i ended up with weird quotes... :)

Comment: So cool! R has the be amongst the coolest languages out there if not THE coolest.

Comment: Problem with sQuote it seems is it uses a different character `‘abc’` . But what we would actually need would be `'abc'`. When run sql it sQuote gives error

Comment: @sjd -- You can get the plain quotes you want by first setting `options(useFancyQuotes = FALSE)`. (See `?sQuote` for some additional options.)

Answer (score 1):

Extending @vodka answer:

```
s <- c("cat", "dog")
a <- "'"
mapply(paste0, a, s, a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Reduce` and `paste0`

```
Reduce(paste0,list("'","a","'"))
 [1] "'a'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something:

```
s <- "cat"
a <- "'"
paste(a,s,a,sep="")
```

Comment: Thx. I used collapse instead of sep.

Answer (score 0):

With `sprintf()`:

```
x <- c("paste", "cat", "print")

sprintf("'%s'", x)
# [1] "'paste'" "'cat'"   "'print'"
```