# R Shiny - conditionalPanel - using the condition & setting inputs equal to a value that includes a single apostrophe

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, rstudio-server

In my conditional panel, I'm setting the inputs equal to a value that includes a single apostrophe in the word.

```
    conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.mood == 'I'm Great'"
)
```

I've been getting this error on the UI webpage:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Solutions tried:
Back-slash

```
    conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.mood == 'I\'m Great'"
)
```

Double Back-slash:

```
    conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.mood == 'I\\'m Great'"
)
```

Paste0:

```
    conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.mood == paste0("'I","'","m Great'")"
)
```

OR

```
    conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.mood == 'paste0("I","'","m Great")'"
)
```

I don't believe I can call paste0 or paste within the condition.

Comment: I think the double backslash should work. Please post a complete code example - meaning, an entire minimal shiny app that shows the problem. It's difficult to give you a solution without reproducing your error.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested code, but going off of this stack overflow [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529976/r-add-single-quote-to-string) and your paste0, I think it should be something like this:

```
conditionalPanel(
        condition = paste0("input.mood == ", "'", "I","'","m Great", "'")
)
```

This is different from yours in that it brings the `input.mood` into the paste0 and it looks like your double quotes are all over the place.